# could improper parameters for dispatchThreadgroups lead to segment fault?

Tags: ios, macos, gpu, metal

I have realized an interpolation function using metal shader. Sometimes, segment faults were reported when carrying out the code:

```
[commandEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadGroups threadsPerThreadgroup:threadGroupCounts];
```

I have checkout other part of my program, and it seemed that this error was caused by dispatchThreadgroups method. I'm not sure whether improper threadGroups and threadGroupCounts could lead to the error. All code was listed as following:

```
void metal_v_texture( void *metal_context, int16_t *dst, uint8_t* _src, int _srcstride, int height, int mx, int my, int width )
{
#define LOCAL_BUF_SIZE 5184 //(64+8)*(64+8)
    int x, y;
    pixel        *src       = (pixel*)_src;
    ptrdiff_t     srcstride = _srcstride / sizeof(pixel);
    int16_t out_buf[LOCAL_BUF_SIZE];
    int16_t *pout = out_buf;
    uint8_t local_src[LOCAL_BUF_SIZE];
    MetalContext *mc = metal_context;

    memset( out_buf,   0, sizeof(int16_t)*LOCAL_BUF_SIZE );
    memset( local_src, 0, sizeof(uint8_t)*LOCAL_BUF_SIZE);

    //copy data to the local_src_buffer
    int s = _srcstride;
    //pcsrc has been checked, it did not lead to segment fault 
    uint8_t *pcsrc = _src - 4*s - 4;
    uint8_t *pcdst = local_src;
    for( int i = 0; i < height+8; i++ )
    {
       memcpy( pcdst, pcsrc, sizeof(uint8_t)*(width+8));
       pcsrc += s;
       pcdst += 72;
    }


    id<MTLDevice> device = mc->metal_device;
    id<MTLCommandQueue> commandQueue = mc->metal_commandqueue;
    id<MTLComputePipelineState> cpipeline = mc->metal_cps_put_hevc_qpel_v;
    assert( device );
    assert( commandQueue );
    assert( cpipeline );

    //in_texture
    int w = 72/4, h = height+4;
    MTLTextureDescriptor *in_desc = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Uint width:w height:h mipmapped:NO];
    id<MTLTexture> in_texture = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:in_desc];
    assert( in_texture );

    MTLRegion texture_region = MTLRegionMake2D( 0, 0, w, h );
    [in_texture  replaceRegion:texture_region mipmapLevel:0 withBytes:local_src bytesPerRow:72];    

    //out_texture
    MTLTextureDescriptor *out_desc = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Uint width:w height:h mipmapped:NO];
    out_desc.usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite;
    id<MTLTexture> texture = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:out_desc];
    assert( texture );

    MTLSize threadGroupCounts = MTLSizeMake(1, 1, 1);
    MTLSize threadGroups = MTLSizeMake([texture width]  / threadGroupCounts.width,
    [texture height] / threadGroupCounts.height,
        1);

    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];
    id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> commandEncoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
    assert( commandBuffer );
    assert( commandEncoder );

    [commandEncoder setComputePipelineState:cpipeline];
    [commandEncoder setTexture:texture    atIndex:0];
    [commandEncoder setTexture:in_texture atIndex:1];

    //after this printf fuction, segment fault happed
    printf("%s %d commandEncoder: %x commandBuffer: %x in_texture: %x device: %x commandQueue: %x pipeline: %x\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, commandEncoder, commandBuffer, in_texture, device, commandQueue, cpipeline );
    [commandEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadGroups threadsPerThreadgroup:threadGroupCounts];
    [commandEncoder endEncoding];

    // synchronize texture from gpu to host mem
    id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> blitEncoder = [commandBuffer blitCommandEncoder];
    [blitEncoder synchronizeTexture:texture slice:0 level:0];
    [blitEncoder endEncoding];


    [commandBuffer commit];
    [commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];


    // Get the data back
    MTLRegion region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, [texture width], [texture height]);
    [texture getBytes:out_buf bytesPerRow: 72*2 fromRegion:region mipmapLevel:0];

    pout = out_buf+4*72+4;
    int16_t *pdst = dst;
    for( int j = 0; j < height; j++ )
    {
        memcpy( pdst, pout, sizeof(int16_t)*width );
        pdst += MAX_PB_SIZE;
        pout += 72;
    }


   //release
   //[in_desc release];
   //[out_desc release];
   [in_texture release];
   [texture release];
   [commandBuffer release];
   [commandEncoder release];
   [blitEncoder release];        
}
```

The device, commandqueue and computepipestat were created outside and passed into this function. The use of prsrc has been checked, it did not lead to segment fault.

```
uint8_t *pcsrc = _src - 4*s - 4;
```

The address of commandEncoder, commandBuffer, in_texture, device, commandQueue anc cpipeline are valid, as shown in the printed information of a segment fault

```
hmetal.m 548 commandEncoder: ea73af30 commandBuffer: ea529440 in_texture: eb0d7200 device: ec014800 commandQueue: ea70dc50 pipeline: ea710d70
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Thanks for viewing my question.

Comment: I suggest for threadGroupCounts to start with at least (8, 8, 1).

Comment: Does it still occur when you dispatch with a thread group size and count of 1x1x1? The issue here is almost certainly that the CPU is reading beyond the bounds of one of your allocations, but it's difficult to tell without a more complete version of your project where it may be going wrong.

Comment: @Marius, ( 8, 8 ,1 ) still failed to work

Comment: @warrenm, dispatching with a thread group size and count of 1x1x1 still failed to work.